# Как скрыть меню при повторном клике jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Имеется вот такой псевдокод, при клике он показывает моё меню, но я хочу что бы при повторном он его опять скрывал, как это можно сделать?

```
<script>
    $('.header-menu-icon').click(function (){
        $(".header-menu-link").css("display", "inline-block");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Можно сделать два класса css `.header-menu-link { display: none }` и `.header-menu-link.active { display: inline-block }` и в jq вместо `.css("display", "inline-block");` использовать `.toggleClass('active');`

Comment: Да спасибо, работает)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать переменную, которая будет изменяться при клике и по ней сверять, открыто ли меню.

```js
let menuOpen = 0;

$('.header-menu-icon').click(function() {
  if(menuOpen == 0) {
    menuOpen = 1;
    $(".header-menu-link").css("display", "inline-block");
  } else if(menuOpen == 1) {
    menuOpen = 0;
    $(".header-menu-link").css("display", "none");
  }
});
```

```css
.header-menu-icon {display: block; width: 30px; height: 30px; background: gray; cursor: pointer;}
.header-menu-link {display: none; width: 50px; height: 100px; background: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="header-menu-icon"></div>
<div class="header-menu-link"></div>
```

Либо использовать классы (мне такой вариант больше нравится).

```js
let menuOpen = 0;

$('.header-menu-icon').click(function() {
  let hasClass = $('.header-menu-link').hasClass('active');
  if(hasClass)
    $('.header-menu-link').removeClass('active');
  else
    $('.header-menu-link').addClass('active');
});

/* Либо использовать вот такой код
$('.header-menu-icon').click(function() {
  $('.header-menu-link').toggleClass('active');
});
*/
```

```css
.header-menu-icon {display: block; width: 30px; height: 30px; background: gray; cursor: pointer;}
.header-menu-link {display: none; width: 50px; height: 100px; background: red;}
/* Добавим класс active */
.header-menu-link.active {display: block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="header-menu-icon"></div>
<div class="header-menu-link"></div>
```